# Get value of second JSON node on same level

Tags: java, json

Hello I have JSON like:

```
 {
    "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "name": "NAME",
        "description": "Login success."
    },
    "message": "Login success.",
    "data": {
        "att_ticket": "TICKET_0625172f00ae7737bbab3c558c877b046e6b23ba",
        "ktk_session_id": "735efe0e9af14eee3aa5839cbc609e66"
    }
 }
```

I am able to read status name but when I try to read `data` attribute `att_ticket` I get

```
JSONObject("data") not found.
```

The code I am using is:

```
String attTicket=object.getJSONObject("data").getString("att_ticket");
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: 1) Post the real JSON

The object you are trying to decode can be a Map<String,Object> in which data will be a Map<String,Object>

Map<String,Object> json = mapper.XX(source);
String attVal = json.get("data").get("att_ticket");

should give you the json. I have mentioned mapper.XX coz I'm not sure what the source of your JSON is. Replace XX with readValue or convertValue

Comment: Which library are you using to get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting `att_ticket` this should work:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(clientstring); 
JSONArray params = obj.getJsonArray("data");
JSONObject param1 = params.getJsonObject();
String ticket = param1.getString("att_ticket")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all your answers guys. It was error returned from the service that was the reason for not getting the data Object.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to validate your json at a place like http://jsonlint.com/.

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "name": "NAME",
        "description": "Login success."
    },
    "message": "Login success.",
    "data": {
        "att_ticket": "TICKET_06232432432432432432dsffdse6b23ba",
        "ktk_session_id": "735efe0e9af14eee3aa5839cbc609e66"
    }
}
```

At this point, you shouldn't have any issues accessing the values you want.